# How do i overwrite the previous line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i want the previous line to be erased after 2 seconds then another line appear on that same line.

ex.

```
import sys
print("hi")
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print("there")
```

This way doesn't work though.

Comment: *Import*ing is *Import*ant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost correct, Make the following changes

```
import sys 
import time                    # Import time module
print("hi",end = "")           # End on the same line and not on next line
sys.stdout.flush()
time.sleep(2)
print("\rthere")               # Use \r (return) to clear the 
                               # line for new words
```

To use the same code on Python 2.6, put the following line at the top of the file:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: that didn't work. it didn't erase the previous line stated than printed the new line

Comment: @JordanMorse It is working perfectly for me. Did you copy the code correctly? (Python 3.4.1)

Comment: i did exactly what you did. It still doesn't erase hi and print there on the same line. It print it like 'hi there'

Comment: @JordanMorse Which version of python and Which OS?

Comment: i have the latest version and im running on windows

Comment: @JordanMorse This works in the command prompt, are you running it on any IDE?

Comment: yes, that is probably why